# Using custom class as ItemsControl Tag in WPF XAML?

Tags: c#, reactjs, wpf, xaml

I have a web app built with ASP.NET and React. I’m trying to port some components to a Windows WPF app, and this is my first time using WPF/XAML. My experience with XAML hasn’t been too bad... it’s like a more-verbose React, but one thing I can’t work out how to do properly is save bind parameters from nested lists to ItemsControl.

In React, I’d use something like ***onClick=“(e)=>this.myFunction(e, parentIndex)”***, so that I could send 2 parameters at once, maybe representing an index and a value, or a childIndex and parentIndex, etc.

It is unclear to me how to properly do this with WPF’s flavour of XAML, and XAML in general. From what I’ve read, I have to use a ICommand (which I feel like is overkill, as the params I’m using are usually not user-input, and instead are references to other objects on the back-end) or set the tag of the initiating object (a button) to a custom class with the amount of attributes I need.

The second approach seems more sensible to me, but I can’t work out how to dynamically do this with an ItemsControl on the XAML frontend — all the tutorials I’ve seen do this in the codebehind, which I don’t think is possible as I’m using an ItemsControl.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass item to command via CommandParameter.
For assign command to mouseEvents you can use InputBindings.

Lets assume that you have ViewModel with command

```
public ICommand SomeClickCommand {get; private set}

public void SomeCLickCOmmandHandler (object parameter)
{
      var yourItem = object as SomeItemType;
}
```

you can assign item to command in DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate TargetType={x:Type someItemType}>
    <Border>
       <Border.InputBindings>
               <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SomeClickCommand , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                   Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" />
        </Border.InputBindings>

        <TextBlock Text={Binding SomeProperty} />
     </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```